# How to extract certain character from data attribute using regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` with certain data attribute. And want to extract certain value from that data attribute.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-space="left-15 right-15">
</div>
<script>
var defaultValue = $('div').attr('data-space').replace('left-15 right-', '') / 5;
console.log(defaultValue);
</script>
```

here `data-space="left-15 right-15"` is a dynamic I will change based on user event.

For example when the data-space changed to `data-space="left-0 right-0"` it will return nan. How can I solve this issue using regex.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-space="left-0 right-0">
</div>
<script>
var defaultValue = $('div').attr('data-space').replace('left-15 right-', '') / 5;
console.log(defaultValue);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var defaultValue = $('div').attr('data-space').replace(/left-(\d)+\sright-/, '')/5;
 
console.log(defaultValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-space="left-0 right-0">
</div>
```